# React app stays blank with Express to deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I can't figure out how to get my react app (created with create-react-app) to work when deploying to heroku.

Without heroku everything works fine. I use `npm start` which uses `react-scripts start` to start the react app and everything works locally as expected.
Now that I want the app to run on heroku I have to use express to serve it's content to the client. I tried this but sadly my browser stays blank. Just a white screen, nothing else. Not even error messages?! Neither in the console nor in the browser's console.

My server's structure looks like this:

- public

  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - manifest.json
  - etc...
- src

  - App.css
  - App.js
  - index.css
  - index.js
  - etc...
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- Procfile
- server.js

Here is my server.js file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);
});
```

Is there any mistake in the file? Or do I maybe use a wrong method to start the server?

I've seen people using `node server.js`, some run `node server.js` in one terminal and `npm start` in another terminal. And some others run just `npm start` but changed the start script in the package.json to `node server.js`. I think I am confused at this point. What's the difference between all those commands?

And what could I do to solve the problem? Can anyone help me? Or do you need any additional code insights to help me?

Comment: Do you have a `build` script in your `package.json` ? If so can you provide that one please? Heroku runs `npm run build` by default and serves that bundle instead of the actual source code. The problem might be over there. Maybe provide your `Procfile` as well, it might shed some light on what Heroku is trying to do.

Comment: Yes I have a build script in my package.json: `"build": "react-scripts build"`. And my Procfile contains just: `web:npm start`. But so far I am just trying to prepare my project for heroku. So I want to run it locally first, second using `heroku local web` and if both runs fine I want to push it to heroku again.

Answer (score 0):

My server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
const port = process.env.PORT || '8080';
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on :${port}`));
```

My Procfile as per heroku:

```
web: node server.js
```

Please note that you should have `build` folder where the production would be picked up by heroku. In addition package.json.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.0.3",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.0.27",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "array-move": "^1.0.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-v4-rtl": "^4.1.1-0",
    "can-use-dom": "^0.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "downshift": "^3.1.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.4",
    "email-regex": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.2.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "luhn": "^2.3.0",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "node_env": "^0.0.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "query-string": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^1.0.0",
    "react-ckeditor-component": "^1.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.17.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-d3-speedometer": "^0.4.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dnd": "^6.0.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^6.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.12.13",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.9",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.12",
    "react-icons": "^3.2.2",
    "react-intl": "^2.7.2",
    "react-joyride": "^1.11.4",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-number-format": "^4.0.4",
    "react-paypal-express-checkout": "^1.0.5",
    "react-placeholder": "^3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.1.1",
    "react-simple-maps": "^0.12.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.8.3",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.0",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "recharts": "^1.3.6",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "save": "^2.3.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "^0.0.54",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">0.25%",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I didn't know I was supposed to run `npm run build` and serve the ./build directory instead of ./public and ./src. Changing this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will run `npm run build` by default when deploying. In your case this is `react-scripts build`. This script will bundle your code into a `build` folder.

---

## Express

This means that your Express middleware should serve static files from your `build` folder instead of your `src` folder.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));
```

should be:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

*(Note: I suggest using an environment variable for this `process.env.STATIC_DIR` or something similar. This way you can easily switch between `src` for local development and `build` for production code and deployment.)*

---

## Procfile

Your procfile states which command Heroku should run after deploying your code. Knowing that Heroku runs `npm run build` you should serve your bundle instead of your source code.

You can do this by changing your procfile like this:

```
web:npm start
```

Should be:

```
web:node server.js
```

This will run your server.js file which serves your static content from the `build` folder.

*(Note: `npm run start` is just for local development. When deploying your web app you should only deploy production code.)*

*(Note: You can test your production build locally by running `npm run build` to bundle your code and `node server.js` to serve it.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now how all these parts fit together and I got it working!

Comment: @Tayfe Great to hear! If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as `accepted answer` for future reference. So others who have similar problems might find your question and be helped as wel.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `create-react-app` doesn't play nicely with Node.
This is what I did to fix my deployment.

`tl;dr` :
Since you created the react app with `create-react-app` you need to use a different buildpack such as: [github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git)

An example workflow taken from Heroku's [docs](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration):

```sh
# You probably did this already
# Create the App
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
git init

# Then you worked on your app

# Now, create the app in heroku with this buildpack...
heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
# ...or add the buildpack in Heroku's dashboard

# Add the files the buildpack bundled for you and deploy
git add .
git commit -m "react-create-app on Heroku"
git push heroku master

# To see your app
heroku open
```

The Procfile (in the root directory) should contain the following:

```
web: bin/boot
```

Once that's in heroku's repo, you can use the CLI to start the web dyno

```
heroku ps:scale web=1:free
```

You can delete your server.js file at this point:
More info here: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#usage

Hope this helps. Cheers!